# Здравствуйте. Хочу написать калькулятор функций (тех функций, которые проходятся в 11 - 12 классе)

Tags: javascript

Изучаю JavaScript, HTML и CSS около месяца, писал сайт-калькулятор и простейшую бегалку, но знаний для таких более сложнных программ не хватает. Я не прошу сделать код за меня, я лишь хотел бы узнать непосредственные команды и функции, которые могут пригодиться мне в этом, не могли бы Вы подсказать, из чего будет состоять программа? Имею в виду функции по типу f(x)=5x2-48x+576. Cпасибо большое всем

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Программа может состоять из множества функций. Вам для калькулятора надо изучить работу с числами в javascript, например тут [https://learn.javascript.ru/number](https://learn.javascript.ru/number)

Comment: Находите задачи по числам и алгоритмам, пытайтесь их решить, не получится, приходите сюда, поможем

Comment: вопрос слишком общий и состоит из множества аспектов. Чтобы ответить на него придется написать ответ по объему равный целой главе в увесистой книге. Постарайтесь задавать более конкретные вопросы и тогда вам обязательно помогут.